# Dynamically creating Caliburn bindings within the back end code of view class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contentcontrol, caliburn

I'm trying to build a tree like structure where all the nodes can be dragged around but I'm failing at being able to create the nodes. I'm building the system in MVVM and I have all the back end stuff set up correctly.  My node design is stored in its own model, view and view model and every time I click on add node I want to be able to create an instance of this and add it to the canvas on my overall design view.  However all I can get is text. I'm assuming this is because is it not binding the view but trying to show the view model.

I've tried to utilize the binding methods within the Caliburn library but cannot seem to get any of them to work.

My idea is to create an instance of ContentControl in the view.xaml.cs class and then add it to the canvas in the view.  but it's transferring the code `cal:View.Model = "{Binding viewmodel}"` into back end code that I cant seem to do.

Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: "My idea is to create an instance of ContentControl in the view.xaml.cs class and then add it to the canvas in the view" That's not MVVM.  Sounds like you need an ItemsControl using a Canvas as its panel and with a bunch of DataTemplates for different types of nodes.  Adding a node is done by an ICommand in the parent VM which adds a new child VM to the ObservableCollection bound to the ItemsControl.  If you aren't familiar with observables (OCs and INPC props) and how WPF uses DataTemplates, stop what you're doing and back up.

Comment: I've tried using the items control method, but items control makes it to structured.  As I want the nodes to be able to be dragged around the canvas I'm not sure whether items control supports that. I have a canvas that supports moveable items and this is the approach I am currently following by using that as my items panel template but it doesn't seem to be working so far.  I was hoping there would be an easy fix without items control.  I know its not strictly MVVM but it was an option I was exploring.

Comment: ItemsControl with a Canvas as its panel.   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17137a3b-de32-41aa-99fb-59ea1f29e353/positioning-items-when-canvas-is-the-itemspanel-of-an-itemscontrol?forum=wpf  You can easily bind the Canvas.X and Canvas.Y values to values on your view model in the UC.  There are plenty of people who have done this and have asked many questions about this (hell, I've done it myself, don't remember if I asked any questions here with issues tho).  Go forth, research!  Create a simple prototype.  It's really easy to accomplish once you understand how to do it.